# Improve performance in free hand drawing using core graphics

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I'm working on a freehand drawing application. Its working good, but it issues memory warning and also there are few crash. When i debug it just found 
drawInRect is where the performance is getting affected.

here is sample code for reference.

```
- (void)drawUsingPointOne:(CGPoint)pointOne pointTwo:(CGPoint)pointTwo
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([self.imageCanvas frame].size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGFloat imageDrawWidth = [self.imageCanvas frame].size.width;
    CGFloat imageDrawHeight = [self.imageCanvas frame].size.height;
    CGRect imageDrawFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageDrawWidth, imageDrawHeight);
    [[self.imageCanvas image] drawInRect:imageDrawFrame]; //this line needs to be replaced

    //Create context
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, midPointOne.x, midPointOne.y);
    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, previousPointOne.x, previousPointOne.y, midPointTwo.x, midPointTwo.y);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, LINE_WIDTH);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor drawStrokeColor].CGColor);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    self.imageCanvas.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

This method is called in the touchesmoved

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        CGPoint firstPoint = some point ;
        CGPoint secondPoint = some point ;
    [self drawUsingPointOne:firstPoint PointTwo:secondPoint];
    }
```

I just googled and found out that i need using CGContextSave and CGContextRestore,but i'm really unaware where to use it. Please help me in getting this resolved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Its working fine, but it issues memory warning and also there are few crash." - soooo, it's not working fine....

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice example by `Nick Lockwood` in his book `IOS Core Animation: Advanced Techniques`. See chapter 13 [Efficient drawing](http://books.google.nl/books?id=QfhdAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT247&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false)